# jQuery Optimize counts of found controls in Div

Tags: jquery, optimization

I am using find like this:

```
var controls = divid.find(':input');
```

which gets me all the input controls in the div.

What I need is to get the counts of each type of control, like in the following.

There's gotta be a better way.

```
var answeredRb = false,
    answeredCb = false,
    answeredTb = false,
    answeredSel = false,
    rbCt = divid.find('input[type=radio]').length,
    rbSelected = divid.find('input[type=radio]:checked'),
    rbSelectedCt = rbSelected.length,
    cbCt = divid.find('input[type=checkbox]').length,
    cbSelected = divid.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
    cbSelectedCt = divid.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length,
    tbCt = divid.find('input[type=text]').length,
    tbs = divid.find('input[type=text]'),
    selCt = divid.find('select').length;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: though I must confess I never used it, it seems fit for underscore groupBy http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Comment: ...countby seems promising too http://underscorejs.org/#countBy

Comment: Thanks, jbl, for your ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this suffice:

```
var results = {};
var rules = ['input[type=radio]', 'input[type=radio]:checked', 'input[type=checkbox]', 'input[type=checkbox]:checked', 'input[type=text]', 'select'];

$(":input").each(function()
{
    for (var i=0; i<rules.length; i++)
    if ($(this).is(rules[i]))
        results[rules[i]] = results[rules[i]]+1 || 1;

});

console.log(results);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SyJxU/

An alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/SyJxU/1/

Comment: Looks interesting, eithed. I'll take a closer look.